# "Automatically enhance my photos" in Windows 10 Photos app no longer available?

Tags: windows-10, photos, windows-10-v1703

Does anybody know, what happened to the "Automatically enhance my photos" option in the Windows 10 Photos app?

[image]

I can't find it in my Photos app of the version 2017.39081.15820.0.

Is this functionality no longer available?

Comment: What version of the Photo application did you last see this option in?

Comment: @Ramhound, I do not remember. I found this picture in the Internet, but I definitely know that I saw this option in my Photos app some months ago. What I am bothering about is that the Photos app theoretically can change the original versions of our picture files if we do not have an option to switch this option on/off. One of the recent versions of Photos app simply enhanced the pictures I am viewing on the fly, so who knows what the MS developers decide to do with our photos next time...